# A bound for the probability that a Brownian motion stays in an interval

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Suppose I have a Brownian motion $X_t$ with $X_0=0$. Let $T$ be the first exit time of the interval $[-1,1]$.

I'm trying to get a "quick" lower bound for the probability that $T$ is very large which is asymptotically reasonable. It's very easy to come up with nice upper bounds, but I can't find a way of bounding it below.

I can get something with the reflection principle, but it's inelegant. Is there a trick or a pretty way of doing it.

Comment: I found a reference: Probability: Theory and Examples by Rick Durrett ( https://www.math.ucla.edu/~biskup/275a.1.20f/PDFs/Durrett-v5.pdf ) Exercise 7.5.1. The relevant theorems for Did's Martingale proof are listed just before the exercises.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb E[\mathrm e^{sT}]=1/\cos(\sqrt{2s})$ for every $0\leqslant s\lt\pi^2/8$ and that $1/\cos(x)\to+\infty$ when $x\to\pi/2$, $x\lt\pi/2$. Thus, for every $a\lt\pi^2/8\lt b$ there exists some finite $C_a$ and $C_b$ such that, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$
C_b-bt\leqslant\log \mathbb P[T\geqslant t]\leqslant C_a-at.
$$

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!!   Do you know where I could find a reference?

Comment: @Tim One way is to use that $(\exp(i\sqrt{2s}B_t+st))_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale, and to apply the OST at $T$.

Comment: @BenDerrett Reference $\ne$ proof.

Comment: @BenDerrett So I have $E[\exp(i \sqrt{2s} B_T + s T)]=1$ by OST. Now I want to use that $E[\exp(i \sqrt{2s} B_T)] = (\exp(i \sqrt{2s}) + \exp(-i \sqrt{2s}))/2 = \cos(\sqrt{2s})$. However that requires independence between $B_T$ and $T$? Maybe I can get away with some symmetry argument, but is there then a way to expand the argument when the interval is $[-2,1]$ say?

Comment: @ThomasAhle $Re[E[\exp(i\sqrt{2s}B_T + sT)]]=E[e^{sT}\cos(\sqrt{2s}B_T)]=E[e^{sT}\cos(\sqrt{2s})]$, so no extra symmetry argument is needed. For the interval $[-2,1]$, define a new Brownian Motion by $B^*_t = (3B_{4t/9} - 1)/2$, and relate the time that $B^*$ hits $[-2,1]$ to $T$. Hope that helps. (If further discussion is required, please open a new question and put the link to it here)

Comment: @BenDerrett I think you are now moving the starting point to $-1/2$, so it's not exactly the same situation. I found a solution in the Rick Durrett book though.

Comment: @ThomasAhle Agreed. The starting point changes, and then the argument goes through with a different time 0 value of the martingale.

Comment: @BenDerrett I was trying to come up with a case where the starting point was closer to one endpoint than the other. I don't think there is a way to handle that with this argument? At least we would have to bound the probability that $B$ hits $0$ before it hits $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @ThomasAhle $E[\exp(i\sqrt{2s}B_T+sT)] = E[\exp(i\sqrt{2s}B_0)]$ by OST. Taking real parts: $\cos(\sqrt{2s})E\exp(sT) = \cos(\sqrt{2s}B_0)$. So $E\exp(sT) = \cos(\sqrt{2s}B_0) / \cos(\sqrt{2s})$

Comment: @BenDerrett You are completely right! Thank you for your patience!